# Arduino - Garbled serial output even at 9600 baud

Tags: arduino

I am doing a project that requires the Arduino to read data from a potentiometer. I was trying to get the potentiometer working so I used this code, which should read the potentiometer and then output it to the serial monitor.

```
int val = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  val = analogRead(A1);
  Serial.println("Head " + val);
}
```

I used the code from https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/potentiometer and changed the code from blinking an LED to outputting the value to Serial where I Am monitoring it using the Arduino IDE's Serial monitor tool and all I get is this

```
⸮⸮>W07⸮⸮7M⸮⸮⸮[+⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮z⸮R⸮⸮⸮a~⸮⸮yo6|⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮߉⸮[⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮7⸮%
G2⸮{⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ݪ}⸮⸮⸮>⸮⸮{⸮K⸮ݻ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮:w⸮⸮⸮⸮6⸮⸮⸮⸮O⸮⸮⸮⸮?w⸮⸮07⸮⸮7M⸮⸮⸮[+⸮⸮⸮}<⸮z⸮R⸮⸮⸮a~⸮⸮yo6|⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮߉⸮[⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮7⸮%
G2⸮{⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ݪ}⸮⸮⸮>⸮⸮{⸮K⸮ݻ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮:w⸮⸮⸮⸮6⸮⸮⸮⸮O⸮⸮⸮⸮?w⸮⸮07⸮⸮7M⸮⸮⸮[+⸮⸮⸮}<⸮⸮m⸮M⸮⸮jo⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮.⸮⸮⸮⸮d⸮⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮.|⸮}⸮⸮⸮啺7|g⸮⸮⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮:⸮N⸮?⸮{⸮n.o⸮⸮e6⸮?l⸮⸮h⸮⸮⸮⸮ϻ⸮⸮⸮⸮ԟy⸮⸮⸮o7s7⸮?u⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮⸮߰⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮~߹h⸮⸮⸮ӿw⸮⸮g⸮⸮⸮T⸮z⸮⸮|⸮t⸮⸮⸮^⸮-⸮o⸮/=⸮ݩ⸮i⸮H⸮⸮ם⸮E⸮⸮ݛ⸮筷?⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮G}⸮⸮U⸮6⸮⸮ۮ⸮2׳⸮⸮⸮⸮G}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮=⸮j⸮k⸮⸮>⸮2X⸮⸮J⸮⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮n⸮⸮⸮⸮i{⸮>⸮}⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮j⸮⸮⸮;⸮⸮un⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮_7⸮⸮⸮⸮y⸮/⸮/⸮⸮⸮u⸮yvN⸮F⸮շy⸮⸮⸮g⸮⸮n⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮l⸮7⸮nw⸮⸮/⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮{,⸮⸮⸮|⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮eſ
⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮j⸮⸮}⸮⸮⸮z⸮]٫ϛ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ݶ⸮⸮ܟ⸮⸮⸮=c⸮o⸮g⸮l^⸮⸮ƭߛ⸮?⸮[9w⸮\[⸮⸮y⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮3⸮yѷ⸮⸮⸮g⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮v⸮⸮⸮]>_⸮⸮⸮ױs⸮'~⸮i;W⸮⸮⸮⸮1ֽܢ⸮⸮⸮'⸮⸮t⸮u⸮⸮]⸮_ڙͿo⸮y⸮W⸮ٗ⸮K⸮⸮_⸮⸮⸮⸮:⸮|M⸮⸮⸮⸮G⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮N⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮<⸮⸮⸮w^⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮e⸮⸮⸮"⸮⸮Xg⸮N⸮n⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮߷⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮c⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮.⸮>⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮n⸮⸮?7?_⸮⸮⸮'>⸮⸮k|ۉ.⸮췅⸮T⸮ϝ⸮=⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮׿}⸮⸮⸮Y⸮⸮Z⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮C⸮⸮9⸮v⸮⸮~>⸮⸮⸮Z⸮z?⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮^⸮Ӿ⸮Md⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮MZK⸮j⸮⸮M⸮׳⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮]/Wꣷ⸮?⸮;o⸮u⸮⸮9⸮⸮⸮Y˧⸮{⸮W⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ݮYn⸮ο⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮;⸮⸮⸮7{}⸮v⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮v⸮⸮7⸮⸮⸮}O+Y+⸮^⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮q⸮⸮z^\⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮~~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮t⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮L⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮+=⸮⸮⸮C⸮⸮Ƭ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮W⸮⸮⸮/⸮⸮⸮5⸮~{{⸮|.⸮;P⸮⸮p⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮oZ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ߝ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮g⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮W⸮Wj⸮oY⸮;⸮⸮/?⸮⸮~⸮6⸮⸮m⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮k⸮_O⸮߃⸮b⸮m⸮⸮kӾ?⸮l⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮X׬>{a⸮⸮[k#⸮/⸮~ݍ⸮⸮⸮⸮_⸮⸮O_⸮9⸮⸮⸮⸮t⸮⸮g⸮⸮⸮⸮*⸮1⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮wߝ;⸮z⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮2⸮⸮⸮⸮O⸮c⸮⸮䝿⸮⸮⸮_Ŭ⸮⸮׹զޫ:⸮⸮旚⸮⸮r⸮⸮oo⸮⸮7⸮⸮⸮O,⸮G~⸮⸮.5⸮⸮⸮,⸮w⸮o⸮⸮⸮A⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮uo⸮⸮⸮?o븨⸮⸮yp⸮~W⸮o⸮⸮⸮iH2⸮⸮8⸮⸮w⸮{⸮⸮C⸮F;⸮⸮!⸮?⸮⸮;⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮m٫⸮?o⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ϻ⸮o.⸮⸮⸮⸮c⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ߴ⸮q"S{⸮c⸮ٻ⸮⸮⸮H⸮~⸮⸮[⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮}⸮w4⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮%⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮t쟕v⸮⸮>⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮oY⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮~c⸮⸮a⸮⸮⸮^q⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮׍⸮⸮⸮ޟәw_⸮⸮O⸮⸮e⸮⸮⸮V⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮o⸮⸮uy⸮8⸮⸮gޟ⸮_⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮.
⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮r⸮R⸮?ݍ⸮⸮⸮͖⸮⸮⸮⸮:;_⸮⸮{⸮^⸮m⸮⸮E_*⸮⸮⸮[⸮⸮\wU⸮g.}⸮ۻ/?⸮⸮}j⸮⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮·⸮y{>⸮⸮#}⸮⸮⸮⸮U⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮|o⸮Q⸮\⸮⸮'⸮ ⸮⸮⸮⸮iZo_⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮8⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮=⸮⸮}zݽ⸮Q⸮w⸮⸮⸮^⸮⸮t⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮|'⸮⸮T⸮⸮⸮⸮ߩ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮   ?⸮3⸮⸮⸮⸮s}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮߽⸮v⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮"⸮⸮>⸮⸮N?⸮ד⸮⸮_W⸮o⸮⎼⸮w⸮G|;⸮V⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮{Jg⸮⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮W⸮3⸮⸮?⸮݌⸮s⸮ew⸮{⸮⸮!⸮⸮g⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮K⸮⸮_⸮⸮⸮⸮V7⸮j[mFԿA⸮q⸮⸮⸮lc⸮⸮⸮.⸮⸮N_ۿ⸮⸮⸮⸮fs}⸮{⸮⸮]⸮Ѷݧ⸮⸮⸮훽⸮⸮n⸮7⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮u⸮⸮⸮=⸮⸮r⸮;⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮=⸮⸮{uߥܽ⸮⸮⸮⸮9⸮⸮⸮.ӷ⸮⸮⸮޹⸮7⸮⸮S⸮;⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮vy⸮⸮e⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮s⸮n⸮⸮_<⸮⸮5Q⸮⸮⸮⸮=⸮{{⸮⸮N⸮⸮⸮sߛ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮v⸮⸮⸮N⸮⸮#z⸮m⸮⸮⸮Q⸮⸮⸮Wq⸮⸮g⸮⸮O⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮m⸮⸮⸮⸮>W⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮p⸮⸮⸮⸮꿿⸮⸮⸮⸮^⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮E[:}⸮⸮⸮o_⸮⸮⸮⸮~⸮⸮?⸮⸮⸮⸮6⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮V⸮z⸮⸮?⸮5⸮~O⸮⸮=⸮⸮⸮⸮f⸮⸮⸮7⸮⸮⸮⸮Z]O⸮⸮ֻ⸮⸮⸮s⸮g[g⸮⸮⸮⸮?sN⸮x⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮0>⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮_⸮⸮⸮e
v?⸮⸮j⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮߅⸮[⸮⸮t⸮3⸮⸮y⸮⸮8~⸮⸮J-4⸮v⸮?⸮⸮ֺ[⸮⸮⸮⸮N%{⸮⸮⸮⸮]⸮wxY/⸮vw⸮⸮⸮.⸮⸮e]⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮e⸮9⸮n⸮>⸮Y!⸮⸮⸮s]⸮⸮⸮7t%⸮⸮ǿ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮_⸮ӷ⸮⸮⸮⸮MC7⸮⸮N⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮u⸮u⸮χu⸮⸮⸮uT}⸮⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ߗ⸮o⸮⸮⸮LG⸮^^M⸮⸮n_⸮⸮t~q⸮⸮⸮~U~~`⸮l⸮-߷⸮l⸮⸮K⸮G⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮U⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ҟ='⸮⸮⸮}Ç
⸮7uO⸮⸮⸮⸮o⸮⸮⸮U_⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮;⸮⸮⸮߼_⸮⸮⸮⸮މ⸮⸮⸮y⸮{⸮W>m_⸮s⸮⸮⸮⸮-ߕȺ⸮'oN_U⸮⸮Ϳ⸮/}t⸮mo~⸮⸮sz⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮~⸮_⸮⸮⸮⸮ù޿⸮&⸮⸮⸮?⸮s⸮y⸮⸮⸮7⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮_⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮z⸮⸮⸮⸮L⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮{⸮⸮go⸮z⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮o⸮⸮⸮~⸮i⸮⸮7⸮⸮~⸮⸮M⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮v⸮⸮y⸮⸮⸮⸮޿⸮⸮⸮⸮2ߏ⸮⸮⸮⸮W⸮x⸮⸮⸮^}⸮U⸮⸮⸮J⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮kya⸮⸮⸮N}?f⸮e⸮{⸮⸮⸮⸮k⸮⸮⸮2⸮>⸮~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮i⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ζ⸮⸮⸮k⸮⸮w⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮Y⸮⸮wi⸮梲ܻ|?w⸮⸮ߥ⸮W⸮⸮⸮⸮eOӞ⸮⸮⸮z⸮⸮⸮o⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮7⸮⸮-J⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮+ڏ⸮⸮߿⸮j⸮}⸮9⸮?⸮⸮⸮[X_⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮.⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮n⸮;⸮ߝP⸮⸮⸮p⸮H⸮F[~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮zL⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ݗ⸮⸮w|^⸮⸮⸮]⸮_⸮⸮⸮k⸮⸮⸮⸮U⸮o4⸮⸮mn⸮⸮>⸮⸮⸮[⸮3⸮/⸮w⸮淯⸮⸮⸮}wD⸮⸮f쿋⸮⸮z⸮⸮H⸮cP⸮YÜ5⸮y⸮?~⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮M}⸮⸮wiP#⸮⸮}⸮L⸮⸮⸮ynx|^⸮wn⸮=⸮泩⸮⸮⸮C⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮~ݳ⸮׍D⸮[⸮⸮⸮,⸮kGȯ⸮⸮⸮Q⸮⸮u⸮⸮⸮O|⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮_|?⸮⸮⸮⸮~ʖ9⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮tNW⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮v⸮⸮e⸮⸮s⸮⸮W⸮⸮⸮⸮~⸮~⸮⸮e⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮q%⸮⸮⸮⸮U⸮=⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮'⸮⸮`⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮ɋ⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮C⸮⸮'⸮Mn⸮ٷ>⸮}⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ߜ⸮⸮⸮]ڞ⸮   ߶_8⸮⸮⸮⸮{.⸮⸮⸮⸮S\+⸮vSǏ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮^⸮⸮\⸮_⸮⸮⸮˫m⸮^⸮⸮=o⸮ůw_yݨ⸮⸮⸮⸮뿜9?_⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮٧⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ǜ⸮ήo⸮⸮f>⸮~5⸮⸮~⸮v⸮v߿?Z⸮%
⸮{⸮|⸮⸮⸮⸮~ou⸮⸮⸮⸮T⸮No⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ֹi&;⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ޛ⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮;⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮?⸮⸮^⸮w;⸮⸮⸮⸮ÿ⸮⸮⸮7⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮ׯ}⸮⸮8⸮⸮⸮F⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮Z⸮⸮??⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮n⸮⸮⸮⸮ _⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮s{⸮⸮⸮⸮U⸮⸮wmt[o⸮7f⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮R⸮⸮⸮L⸮|>⸮M0⸮⸮v⸮%v֟}⸮⸮⸮j7⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮e{n⸮⸮⸮⸮{⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮N}}⸮⸮CsLB⸮⸮⸮j⸮⸮x輣⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮#_⸮y⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮P⸮⸮⸮Z⸮(6⸮_⸮[K<⸮ם⸮_⸮{⸮⸮싛⸮߼5:?k⸮⸮߿⸮~⸮ɫ⸮⸮⸮~⸮⸮⸮K⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮x⸮⸮9⸮ɖ⸮⸮⸮]⸮⸮⸮|[⸮⸮?⸮⸮>eOs⸮⸮⸮⸮Z⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮A?3⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮~⸮⸮[⸮⸮⸮⸮8<⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮⸮}69?⸮⸮⸮⸮K⸮⸮⸮Sb⸮eJ⸮⸮oO⸮⸮''⸮⸮⸮뷳⸮O⸮⸮⸮⸮G_⸮⸮⸮.⸮⸮{⸮⸮
```

It works fine when using the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please Note:**

1. First make sure that the baud rate used in the sketch is same as the baud rate used in the Serial Monitor
2. Use a delay of 10 milliseconds for stability: `delay(10);`
3. The `val` variable is `int`, so better to use Serial.printline with String Constructor as:

   ```
   Serial.println("Head " + String(val);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The baud rate in your code and the baud rate chosen in the Serial Monitor window are different. make sure they match and the output should then be legible.